# Using "Show values as" option in Excel 2007 pivot table when source is SSAS cube?

Tags: excel, service, pivot, pivot-table, analysis

I have an Excel 2007 pivot table showing "Year" across the top and "Month" down the side.  What I am trying to do is represent the values as "% Difference" from the same month of the previous year.  (Ex.  If Jan-07 is $100,000 and Jan-08 is $120,000, I would like Jan-08 to show '20%').  However, every time I try to do this (using the "Show values as" tab of Value Field Settings) all of my numbers go to '#N/A'.  Is there a way to do this using an Analysis Services cube as the data source?  When I do this exact same thing using data on a different sheet as the data source for the pivot table, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is any way of doing this in Excel, but you could create a calculated measure in your cube that would do it.

The MDX expression would look something like the following:

```
([Measures].[Amount] - ([Date].[Year].PrevMember, [Measures].[Amount])) 
/ ([Measures].[Amount])
```

Comment: That is a good idea.  I know I mentioned year-to-year in my question but they may also want to look at month-to-month or quarter-to-quarter.  I would have to create three of these measures and teach them which one to use...  I just can't figure out why the default Excel functionality won't work when the data source is a SQL Server cube...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ref period to period comparisons, you could use the following calculation script.
`YearMonthDate` is the hierarchy on the date dimension, but you could have quarter in there too for your requirement.

> /* The CALCULATE command controls the aggregation of leaf cells in the
>   cube. If the CALCULATE command is deleted or modified, the data within
>   the cube is affected. You should edit this command only if you
>   manually specify how the cube is aggregated.
>   */

```
CALCULATE; 
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].PrevPeriod
 AS ([Measures].[Count],  [Date].[YearMonthDate].CURRENTMEMBER.PREVMEMBER ), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
VISIBLE = 1  ; 

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].PeriodChange
 AS ([Measures].[Count] - [Measures].[PrevPeriod]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
VISIBLE = 1  ;     
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].PercentChange
 AS (
        [Measures].[PeriodChange]/
        IIF(    ([Measures].[PrevPeriod] = 0), 
                [Measures].[Count],
                [Measures].[PrevPeriod]
            )
    ), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Percent", 
VISIBLE = 1;     
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].YearToDate
 AS (
       SUM(PeriodsToDate([Date].[YearMonthDate].[Year Code]), [Measures].[Count])
    ), 
FORMAT_STRING = "#,#", 
VISIBLE = 1;
```